# Cannot connect to mssql using rust/tiberius

Tags: sql-server, rust, database-connection, connection-string

I have the following connection-string to connect to local MS-SQL Server version `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125) - 15.0.2101.7 (X64)`

```
Data Source=<PC name>\\<instance name>;Initial Catalog=<db name>;User Id=sa;Password=<password>;
```

It works very well with my `C#` code.

I also activated both Windows login and SA login

I would like to connect to that database from rust using [tiberius](https://docs.rs/tiberius/latest/tiberius/index.html) and [tokio](https://tokio.rs/) runtime

So I did follow their documentation example code,

I checked multiple combinations of commented lines below, still cannot connect to my db

```rs
//let mut config = Config::from_ado_string("<connection string above>").expect("failed");
//let mut config = Config::new();
//config.host("<pc name here>");
//config.host("<pc ip here>");
//config.host("<pc name here>\\<instance name here>");
//config.host("localhost");
//config.host("127.0.0.1");
//config.host("0.0.0.0");
//config.port(<port, usually 1433>);
//config.instance_name("<instance name here>");
//config.database("<db name>");
//config.authentication(AuthMethod::sql_server("sa", "<password here>"));
//config.trust_cert();

let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
```

Experience these type of errors:

```
Os { code: 10061, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." }
```

I cannot spot what I am missing there.
Guessing that instance name confuses it, rather than directly connecting to host

Comment: Setting a port number and a instance name doesn't make much sense, choose one or the other. For an instance name you need SQL Browser service to be running. Or set a static port number in SQL Server Configuration. Are you connecting from the same machine or a different machine?

Comment: Yeah, that is true, different instance names refer to different port numbers, I did not uncomment them in one go, just for example cases I have tested. And yes my sql server and app is on the same machine

Comment: Wow, really, you've got to manage your own TcpStreams? Rust is so... interesting.

Comment: If you need to use instance names then it seems you're going to need a library that can talk to the SQL Browser service using SSRP ([SQL Server Resolution Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wpo/c67adffd-2740-435d-bda7-dc66fb13f1b7)) over udp/1434. It's the Browser service's job to take instance names and resolve them to the port(s) that the instance is listening on, then the client can attempt to connect to the proffered ports (firewalls permitting).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlwaysLearning,
I managed to find my issue.
Issue was on the port side, since it is named instance it is different than 1433 I was using wrong port number
In order to find the exact port for that instance we need to query to SQL Browser using SSRP protocol
Using this simple C# code you can do that

```cs
//see this link for documentation
//https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MC-SQLR/%5bMC-SQLR%5d-210625.pdf
var remote = IPEndPoint.Parse("127.0.0.1:1434");
var client = new UdpClient();
client.Connect(remote);
const byte CLNT_UCAST_EX = 03;
client.Send(new byte[1] { CLNT_UCAST_EX });
var buffer = client.Receive(ref remote);
//here buffer becomes like:
//..ServerName;...;InstanceName;...;IsClustered;..;Version;...;tcp;62056;;
// 62056-> is my port number
```

I used 62056 as port number in my rust code and it worked